# Redirect domain to a subfolder of another domain ... !?

Tags: .htaccess

I stupidly did overwrite a .htaccess file and now some redirects doesn't work anymore.

Before this action the domain www.duodyade.nl was going to www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyde.nl ... not anymore ... :(

As far as I understand this ... via DNS duodyade.nl has been redirected to the IP of marijevijselaar.nl (93.94.226.77) ... and in the .htaccess on the root of marijevijselaar.nl there were some rules which redirect visitors to marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyde.nl

What were these rules? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Probably rewrite rules. You may try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.duodyade\.nl$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl$1 [P]
```

The `P` in the rule flag stands for proxying.

(and remember to do backups!)

Comment: Is there a `www.duoyde.nl` directory under the main site's DocumentRoot?

Comment: As far as I understand you: yes there is. www.duodyde.nl is the name of a folder in a subdirectory direct after the root (marijevijselaar.nl). The path is http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl

Comment: Oops! There was a mistake in the rule, a spelling error -- now fixed (it was `duodye` instead of `duodyade`). Now fixed, can you retry?

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry! This is the url it gives: http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyde.nlindex.php ... and it would be very nice if the url in the browser shows: www.duodyade.nl ... but if that's possible ...!??!

Comment: I'm working with Chrome. And Chrome has a very powerful cache ... %$#%@$ ... everything is working now only with a minor change in your code: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.duodyade\.nl$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks @fge ... but is it possible to get a 'clean' url in the browserwindow that only says: www.duodyade.nl ... !?

Comment: Well, as you use `R=301`, no... This is why I used `P` (which I don't understand why it doesn't work). Try and remove the `R=301` from your flags.

Comment: With only [P] I get www.duodyade.nl as url but also a error-default page ... :(

Comment: Try only `L`, then. I never use it in my setups, but if it works for you... (I also never use .htaccess files, only vhosts)

Comment: [L] doesn't work either ... gives http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl/ ... sorry!

Comment: Have you tried `P` only with the corrected redirection? What error-page do you get exactly? Is it a 404, a 500, a 403, other?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.duodyade\.nl$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl$1 [P]` gives as url http://www.duodyade.nl/ of a 404!

Comment: There needs to be a slash before `$1`. So `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl/$1 [P]`

Comment: Thanks Gerben. Now I only need a rewrite rule so that the url http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/www.duodyade.nl/ will be visible as www.duodyade.nl ... ??